# Why my server freezes when using long pull with Ajax?

Tags: php, jquery

When I'm taking my query using Ajax on jQuery, o try use the method of long pull but my server is shutdown or dont response, my website becomes too slow like in stanby, or freezed what can i do?

MY PHP;

```
session_start();
$chat=new chat;
$class=new tools;

$idenvia=isset($_GET['idenvia'])? $_GET['idenvia']: '';
$idreceptor=isset($_GET['idreceptor'])? $_GET['idreceptor']: '';
$cantidad= isset($_GET['cantidad'])? $_GET['cantidad']: '';
$control=$_GET['control'];
//$ultima_modif=isset($_SESSION['fecha'])?$_SESSION['fecha']:0;
if($control==1){
echo json_encode($chat->leer_chat($idreceptor,$idenvia,$control,$cantidad,NULL));
}
if($control==2){
$dir='log/log_'.$_SESSION['id'].'.txt';
$ultima_modif=filemtime($dir);  
$modifica_actual=isset($_GET['tiempo'])? $_GET['tiempo']: 0;//0
set_time_limit(0);
while($ultima_modif<=$modifica_actual){
    clearstatcache();
    $ultima_modif=filemtime($dir);
    sleep(1);



    //echo '{"0":{"activo":2}}';    
    //flush();
}

           $res=$chat->leer_chat($_SESSION['id'],NULL,$control,$ultima_modif);  
        echo json_encode($res); 
        //unlink($dir);
        flush();    


    }
```

This is my JQUERY code, here i take th response of my php with AJAX

```
 function leer_chat_interval(){
    $.ajax({
        url:enlace,
        type:'GET',
        async:true,
        data:{'control': 2,'tiempo':tiempo},
        success:function(dato){
            eval('var json='+dato);
                if(json[0].activo==1){
                    //if(json.length!=0){   
                        leer_chat(json[0].idenvia,json[0].idrecibe,1,json[0].nombre,json[0].mifoto,1,1);
                        $('#msg_chat'+json[0].idrecibe).attr('name',"{'recibe':'"+json[0].idenvia+"','envia':'"+json[0].idrecibe+"','foto':'"+json[0].mifoto+"'}");
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            $('#header_chat'+json[0].idenvia).css('background-color','#09C')
                            setTimeout(function(){
                                $('#header_chat'+json[0].idenvia).css('background-color','#F90')
                            },1000)
                        },1000);
                        tiempo=json[0].tiempo;
                        noerror=true;

                    }else{noerror=false;}
                },
        datatype:"json",        
        complete:function(dato){
                if(!noerror){
                setTimeout(function(){
                    leer_chat_interval()
                    },5000)
                }else{
                    leer_chat_interval();
                    noerror=false;

                    }
            },

            timeout:30000

        }); 

}
```

Comment: Can anyone figure out what OP is asking?

Comment: I think I kinda... sorta.. wait what?

Comment: I'm not a php programmer, so maybe a silly question, but is there anything that exits out of the `while(1) {}` endless loop?

Comment: ok, i speak spanish and my english is not very good, then i sorry for the grammer, ok my question is about the long pull, i have problem having response from server, the server become slowly, i think is maybe for the infinite loop, but my idea is keep connection open with ajax, i mean?

Comment: oh, and `eval('var json='+dato);`... ummm, why?

Comment: ok MrObrian is the same as json=eval('('+dato+')')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is this:

```
while(1)
```

You are not supposed to have a script looping infinitely to handle your ajax "long polling"; instead each ajax call runs through a finite request, collects the result, and repeat. What is happening in your example is that everytime your ajax request fires, a new infinitely running script is started; naturally the server collapses after a accumulating several of these.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Mahn, you have a solution to me, i will change the code with other example and please tell me if is better than before